# Powershell: Hiding second function parameter when first is already defined

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to implement API of our product using Powershell. E.g., I'd like to create a function `Remove-OurProductEntity`. This function should have both `-ById` and `-ByFullPath` parameters to know which entity to delete. They shouldn't be both mandatory, but only one of them.

If user specified one of them in the command line, the second mustn't appear in autocompletion and Powershell shouldn't ask user to define the second. Moreover, if user specified both, function should ask to define the only one.

Is it possible to be done in Powershell? Or I should handle all the logic inside the function?
Powershell has really COOL language, and guess, something similar should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parameter sets are your friend.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/12/23/powershell-v2-parametersets.aspx

Comment: You are the GOD. Or Powershell :) 10x a lot, as always I can say -- so simple :)